# Imitate command line execution from within code

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a python project that is intended to be executed by running the head routine from the command line, i.e.:

```
python ssd.py --train
```

However, since this is a machine learning model and I don't have a GPU, I want to run the project entirely within Google Colab. This means I can't start files using the command line (or at least I don't know how). The workaround I've chosen is to use a single notebook as the header routine.

MWE-sketch (edited):

**launcher.ipynb**

```
!cp drive/MyDrive/.../ssd.py
from ssd import SSD
SSD("train")
```

**ssd.py**

```
...

__init__():
   # here is code that will
   # result in an error unless
   # the code below is executed first

...

# the code below is not inside any function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # here is code that
    # must be executed first
```

If I type `python ssd.py --train` into the command line, the code in ssd.py proper is executed first. If I use launcher.ipnyb, the code in `__init__()` is executed first, resulting in an error.

Comment: You can edit `ssd.py`, right? If the `__main__` entry point used when `--train` is passed isn't currently accessible as a library function, you can edit the code to _make_ it accessible that way

Comment: If you _don't have_ a `__name__ == '__main__'` guard to stop things that should only be done during command line execution from happening when loaded as a library, then add one.

Comment: (Because the question isn't showing enough code to let us reproduce your exact problem, we're having to do a lot of guesswork here; a proper [mre] would be more amenable to answers).

Comment: Apologies. I expected that the problem to be trivial and a common work-around to be known (which I take it isn't the case), so I thought the description was sufficient. I've tried to edit in something approximating a MWE.

Comment: Okay, that's very helpful. So, can you move the code that's currently in `if __name__ == '__main__':` block into a function and make the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block call that function? That way other library users will be able to invoke that function themselves.

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly: if the new function is called `setup`, then the code in __launcher.ipynb__ would have to become `import ssd ; ssd.setup("train") ; ssd.SSD("train")`? (Because if I only do what you just said, the problem that `__init__()` is immediately executed once I call `ssd.SSD("train")` would remain.)

Comment: Unless `__init__` is already run upon importing the module, in which case I don't think the proposed solution would work.

Comment: Ok I've done it (posted the solution as an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it to work like this:

**ssd.py**

```
import sys as _sys

...

__init__():
   # here is the same code as before

...

def set_args(args):
    _sys.argv[1:] = args

def setup():
    # here is code that was previously
    # outside any function (i.e., right below)

# the code below is not inside any function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

**launcher.ipynb**

```
!cp drive/MyDrive/.../ssd.py
import ssd
ssd.set_args(["--train"])
ssd.setup()
```

This seems like way too complex and primitive of a solution, but I guess there's nothing better?